# Pass hashed password as a value to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have an exported list of mail accounts and hashed passwords in the file list_of_mails, like the following

```
test@test.com:$1$MWC5DJEw$ONBlA7X.xiwgQaPND/EXb/
```

With the colon (:) as a delimiter I pass each column to a variable.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
MAILACC=$(echo "$line"|cut -d":" -f1)
HASHPASS=$(echo "$line"|cut -d":" -f2|tr -d '\n')
echo "${MAILACC} ${HASHPASS} 0"
done < list_of_mails
```

But in the output of the script the 0 replaces the first character in each line so I get

`0est@test.com $1$MWC5DJEw$ONBlA7X.xiwgQaPND/EXb/`

The desired output is

`test@test.com $1$MWC5DJEw$ONBlA7X.xiwgQaPND/EXb/ 0`

PS. I have tried with and without `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: You left out the interesting part. Show the part before `do`.

Comment: Where is the rest? Are you changing `IFS`?

Comment: `in the file list_of_mails` The input file has dos line endings.

Comment: @KamilCuk Indeed! I dos2unix the list_of_mails and it is now working properly. Thank you.

Comment: `IFS=` is for when you *don't* want to split the line. The first two lines of the body suggest otherwise. `while IFS=: read -r MAILACC HASHPASS; do`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed dos line endings.

I installed dos2unix utility and used it to fix the issue.

On CentOS 7 I ran the following:

```
yum install dos2unix

dos2unix myscript.bash
```